# How to make break line inside an instruction in Apache httpd.conf

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

I would like to make line break in my Apache configuration file - httpd.conf. Is it possible? If yes what is the special character to signal such a line break?

So far I tried with backslash, what always resulted in "invalid command error" while checking with configtest.

Answer (score 4):

backslash works in .htaccess Apache 2.2 (should work in httpd.conf too) just make sure there's no other characters or white space between the backslash and the end of the line 
.htaccess - splitting a directive onto 2 lines [demo](http://www.w3-video.com/htaccess/htaccess_syntax.php)

Comment: The link is broken. Please include the essentials part of your link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some Googling on this one.

I think

```
\r
```

is what you're after, unless that's what you meant by "with a backslash".  Let us know how it goes.